# Excel - Transpose Dynamic Columns into Rows in different sheet and copy necessary data items

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in the format below in Sheet 1:

[image]

I want to reorganize the data in format below in Sheet 2:
The length for "Identifier" will be dynamic.
I have tried building macros for transpose with loops and copy range but havent been successful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the macros you've created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  But you would have to rearrange the final results' columns to move the "Identifier" column to the start of the result set.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim A, B, R, C As Long
    Dim x() As Variant
    Dim y() As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        Range("A1").Select

        A = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        x = Range("A1", "I" & A)
        y = Range("J1", "Z" & A)


        For R = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
            B = R + 0
            For C = 1 To UBound(y, 2)
                If (y(R, C)) <> "" Then
                    Range("A" & B, "H" & B).Copy
                    Range("A" & A + 1).PasteSpecial
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Range("I" & A + 1).Value = y(R, C)
                    A = A + 1
                Else
                GoTo xxx:
                End If

            Next C
xxx:
        Next R

        Range("A1").Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are after, here is a macro that does that.  When it starts it asks you to select the top left corner of the source data (it defaults to the active cell) and then it asks for the top left corner of the destination - while the selection box is up you can select the cell with the mouse if you don't want to type it in.  Put this code in a Module:

```
Sub TransposeByLastColumn()

'get the top left corner of the source
Dim Source As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set Source = Application.InputBox("Select Source:", "Source", "=" & ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If Source Is Nothing Then Set Source = ActiveCell

'get the top left corner of the destination
Dim Destination As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set Destination = Application.InputBox("Select Destination:", "Destination", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If Destination Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'calculate the number of headers
Dim HeaderColumns As Long
HeaderColumns = 0
While Source.Offset(0, HeaderColumns).Value <> vbNullString
    HeaderColumns = HeaderColumns + 1
Wend

'copy the headers
Dim HeaderIndex As Long
Destination.Offset(0, 0).Value = Source.Offset(0, HeaderColumns - 1).Value
For HeaderIndex = 1 To HeaderColumns - 1
    Destination.Offset(0, HeaderIndex).Value = Source.Offset(0, HeaderIndex - 1).Value
Next

'copy the data
Dim SourceRowIndex As Long
Dim DestinationRowIndex As Long
Dim DataColumnIndex As Long
Dim IdentifierColumnIndex As Long
SourceRowIndex = 1
DestinationRowIndex = 1
While Source.Offset(SourceRowIndex, HeaderColumns - 1).Value <> vbNullString
    IdentifierColumnIndex = 1
    While Source.Offset(SourceRowIndex, HeaderColumns - 1 + IdentifierColumnIndex - 1).Value <> vbNullString
        Destination.Offset(DestinationRowIndex, 0).Value = Source.Offset(SourceRowIndex, HeaderColumns - 1 + IdentifierColumnIndex - 1).Value
        For DataColumnIndex = 1 To HeaderColumns - 1
            Destination.Offset(DestinationRowIndex, DataColumnIndex).Value = Source.Offset(SourceRowIndex, DataColumnIndex - 1).Value
        Next
        IdentifierColumnIndex = IdentifierColumnIndex + 1
        DestinationRowIndex = DestinationRowIndex + 1
    Wend
    SourceRowIndex = SourceRowIndex + 1
Wend

'show the result
Destination.Worksheet.Activate: Destination.Select

End Sub
```